# ".int" vs ".byte" for creating an array on GNU assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, gnu-assembler, att

I am at odds to understand why after initializing an integer array using `.int` doesn't work with `movl` however doing it with `.byte` works flawlessly.

P.S. I'm using AT&T syntax just so that it is clear from the beginning

Here's the code:

```
.data
    IntArray:
        .int 1, 2
    
    CharArray:
        .byte 1,2

.text

    .globl _start

    _start:
            movl IntArray, %eax <--- fails
            movb CharArray, %eax <-- works
```

By the way is this the 'right' way to copy the base address into the register since it is copying the first byte and not the address which is what I want.

I have searched dozens upon dozens of links and I've only seen people initializing arrays using `.byte`. So what use is `.int` for? Or perhaps I haven't used it properly.

Comment: what assembler do you use? Because that doesn't look like you are using the GNU assembler.

Comment: Sorry I removed some non printable characters that got left out. I force my vim to print them as I had a nasty problem with them sometime back. And I copied from the vim editor directly (although removed them but apparently some got left out :()

And yes it is very much the GNU assembler

Comment: I was confused because the layout is very strange. Normally labels go on the first column and directives (such as `.data` or `text`) go into the same column as mnemonics (i.e. the second column). Your layout is confusing.

Comment: Ah! Now you changed your question! Please always post the code that causes the error, not something you made up. Also, always post the error messages you got, otherwise it can be hard to figure out what “... fails” means.

Comment: Note that your code does not copy the base address of `IntArray` and `CharArray`, it copies some bytes *at* the base address. Are you sure that's what you want? If you actually want to copy the base address, write `movl $IntArray,%eax` or `movl $CharArray,%eax`.

Comment: Downvoted because you fail to explain how `movl IntArray, %eax` fails. Please read [ask] and remember that a good question comprises these parts: 1) what you want to do 2) what code you wrote to do that 3) what you expected to happen and 4) what happened instead (including all error messages you got). Without all four parts, it's very hard to answer a question as we have to guess the missing things, which often isn't possible.

Comment: Actually `movl IntArray, %eax` apparently copies the first entity or rather the first long number at address `IntArray` into reg `eax`

Nonetheless, your comments have given me enough hints and I am sorry I was no able to post the correct question. I was able to figure out the solution and I am off the start now. Will repost the question as well as my own answer

Comment: That's okay. Just remember: Always post in what way something didn't work. “It doesn't work” is a very frustrating sentence to me because I have no idea how you expected the thing to work. Always explain what your expectations are and what happened instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    movb CharArray, %eax
> ```

`movb` moves one byte. `eax` is a doubleword register, you can't move a byte to a doubleword register with `mov`. Either use `movzbl` or `movsbl` to do a zero extending or sign extending move, or change the destination register into a byte register like `%al`.

That's the only thing I see that is wrong with your code. No idea why you think that `.int` is at fault.

Comment: no that one was for you folks obviously!!!! Nonetheless it is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the hints in this question and the comments here is the code that finally works!

```
.data
    IntArray:
        .int 11, 22, 33, 44, 55

    CharArray:
        .byte 55, 2, 3, 4

.bss
    .comm BufferSpace, 1000

.text

    .globl _start

    _start:
            movl $IntArray, %eax
            movl $2, %ebx
            movl 0(%eax, %ebx, 4), %edx
            movl $99, 0(%eax, %ebx, 4)
            nop

            #exit the program
            movl $1, %eax
            movl $0, %ebx
            int $0x80
```

Was making some silly mistakes as pointed out regarding the reg names and sizes as well as not using `$` to get the base address of the array

Comment: This doesn't even answer the question.  `movb  <anything>, %eax` would have failed, too, even `movb (%eax, %ebx, 1), %eax`

Comment: Beyond the assembler spitting warning messages about it replacing eax with al, it assembles and links without a glitch

Comment: My point was that this answer doesn't explain what exactly was wrong with `movb CharArray, %eax`, and this "answer" doesn't even use CharArray at all.  I'm glad you got your problem solved, and posting your working version as an answer is usually a good thing, but I'm not sure this will help anyone else with the same problem.  (Maybe it will if they also read all the other comments and so on, but SO answers are supposed to stand on their own).